# ddmlib get native library info

Tags: android-sdk-tools

My task is to analyze method calls and corresponding native libraries of an android app by using ddmlib. I started with creating a simple app for testing purposes that uses jni for calling a function implemented in C (which squares a given number). Then I implemented IMethodProfilingHandler:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(byte[] data, Client client) {
MethodCallExtractor extractor = MethodCallExtractor.GetInstance();
    List<MethodCall> calls = extractor.extract(data, client);
    System.out.println("methodcalls:");
    for(MethodCall call : calls){
        System.out.println(call);
    }
    printNativeLibraries(client);
}
```

works and prints the call of the jni function. MethodCallExtractor is a simple parser that returns a List of MethodCalls. My problem is that

```
private void printNativeLibraries(Client client){
    ClientData clientData = client.getClientData();
    while(clientData.getNativeLibraryMapInfo().hasNext()){
        System.out.println("library: " + clientData.getNativeLibraryMapInfo().next().getLibraryName());
    }
}
```

does not print anything. Why is the library containing my C function (libsquared.so in my case) not listed in NativeLibraryMapInfo? What do I have to trigger to get NativeLibraryMapInfo initialized properly?

I spent hours experimenting with 'requestNativeHeapInformation()', 'requestAllocationDetails()', 'requestThreadUpdate()' and 
'executeGarbageCollector()' without success and I cannot find any useful documentation about this issue.

I am using ddmlib-r13